# subtotal by groups in report builder

Tags: reporting-services, grouping, reportbuilder

I am new to SSRS and report builder and I am having difficulty getting it to do what I want. I have a report that uses 2 parameters which you can select multiple values. One of the paremters is years. When I select lets say 2 years 2010 and 2011 I want to be able to have a subtotal that shows after each year, but right now it shows the totals at the end and it's totalling both years together. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Do you have a "Row Group" based on your year field?

Comment: under the row groups section on the bottom left of my screen I have the year grouping there.

Comment: Then you should be able to simply select that group, right click, and select "Add Group Subtotal" and place you SUM(FieldName) in the totals text box of the new subtotal row.

Comment: OK heres what I did. When you first create the report it automatically gives you a row group defaulted to (Details) I than right click that and select add group and choose parent group and select the year field to group by. Once that year group is created I right click on that year row group and select add total and choose after, but this still isn't working and only shows one total at the end instead of a toal after each year.

Comment: That should work. Maybe the grouping is up one level higher somehow. It sounds like an easy enough report. I would just create a test report and only include the year and one other value and play around with the grouping until you are spot on.

Comment: funny you mentioned that. I actually did create a smaller test report to play around with. The problem was after I added my grouping for year I was right clicking on the year grouping and clicking add total, but what I should have been doing was after adding the year grouping I should have than clicked on the detail grouping and clicked add total. I hope that doesn't sound too confusing. But thank you for all the help I appreciate it.

Comment: Are you still struggling with this? If so is it possible for you to include a link to your existing design so we can advise further?

Comment: problem solved. The issue was after adding my row group I was totalling on the year group instead of the deatails group.